# send email in Python and list items as email content not as attachment

Tags: python, smtp

I am trying to send an email containing list of URLs along with message stating these are urls for example:

```
BADURL = ['abc.123.com','xyz.456.com','rtf.892.com']
```

Requiring output

Following are BAD URLs

```
abc.123.com
xyz.456.com
rtf.892.com
```

I am writing following code but I am getting message as email body and urls as an attachment. I don't want to send URLs as attachment instead I just want them to be listed in the email. Following is my code:

```
message = multipart.MIMEMultipart('mixed')

message['Subject'] = 'Policy.txt file update'

message['From'] = sender

message['To'] = ','.join(destination)

message['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)

message.attach(text.MIMEText('Following are BAD URLs'))

message.attach(text.MIMEText('\n'.join(y),'plain'))

print('sending message')enter code here

print (message.as_string())

try:

z = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')

z.sendmail(sender, destination, message.as_string())

z.quit()

except(smtplib.SMTPException, IOError) as e:

z.quit()

print(str(e))
```

Comment: You're explicitly going out of your way to create a multipart/mixed, and then to attach separate text messages as attachments. If you don't want to do that, just don't do that.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the corresponding part of your code by these

```
message = multipart.MIMEMultipart('alternative')

message.attach(text.MIMEText('\n'.join(y),'html'))
```

and when you include the URL-s, embrace them into  tags; say put

```
<a href="abc.123.com">some title here</a>
```

in your message.

This should work.

Comment: This will make just the URLs show up if viewed as HTML, and just the header if viewed as text.